# How to execute a function several times asynchronously and get first result

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have a function `get_data(request)` that requests some data to a server. Every time this function is called, it request data to a different server. All of them should return the same response.

I would like to get the response as soon as possible. I need to create a function that calls `get_data` several times, and returns the first response it gets.

**EDIT:**

I came up with an idea of using multithreading.Pipe(), but I have the feeling this is a very bad way to solve it, what do you think?:

```
def get_data(request, pipe):
    data = # makes the request to a server, this can take a random amount of time
    pipe.send(data)

def multiple_requests(request, num_servers):
    my_pipe, his_pipe = multithreading.Pipe()

    for i in range(num_servers):
        Thread(target = get_data, args = (request,his_pipe)).start()

    return my_pipe.recv()

multiple_requests("the_request_string", 6)
```

I think this is a bad way of doing it because you are passing the same pipe to all threads, and I don't really know but I guess that has to be very unsafe.

Comment: the most straightforward way I can think of is to use the first value yielded by python 3's [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed)

Comment: Probably you can use python thread safe queues to return result of thread execution. It's a safe and not blocking way. Please have a look at
[link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Comment: @roippi may I please have a simple example of how to use that function? I am having a hard time trying to comprehend how it works...

Comment: @roippi: And presumably, `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool.imap_unordered` (the `.dummy` to get the thread-based version of the `Pool`) would fill the same niche (and work on both Py2 and Py3).

Comment: Can you add a callback to `get_result`? That's a good way to do async.

Comment: @ReutSharabani how can I do that? The function must be blocking until the first result is provided. I dont know how to do that with a callback.

Comment: I thought it is your function. If not than that's irrelevant.

Comment: I placed that just so people can understand what I want to do (get only one result) but thats not actual code, thats why I said it was pseudopython.

Comment: I ping all of you to check the question edit. Can you tell me if that implementation would be safe?

Comment: @roippi `results = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_time=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED).done` should work too, though you'd then have to loop and call `response = results.pop().result()` until an exception is not raised due to the possibility of canceled or error-state futures.

Answer (score 1):

I think [redis rq](http://python-rq.org/docs/) will be good for it. `get_data` is a job what you put in the queue six times. Jobs executes async, in the docs your also can read how to operate with results.